# How to plot in Latex with Gnuplot?

Tags: latex, gnuplot

Earlier I have used Gnuplot and created a `pdf`-file which I then implemented via `includegraphics` in my `Latex`-document.

Isn't there a better way to plot directly from the `Latex`-document with `Gnuplot`?

Comment: If you want to handle your graphs entirely within your Latex document, `pgfplots` probably offers better Latex-integration than gnuplot.

Answer (score 3):

Basically u can just follow this [Youtube-Tutorial](https://youtu.be/7IfbKQ2dbTU)

So here are the Steps:

**Step 1: Set environment variables**

After having installed [MikTex](http://miktex.org/download), [TexStudio](http://www.texstudio.org/) and [Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/download.html) click on `Start` -> Rightclick on `Computer` -> `Settings` -> `Advanced Systemsettings` -> `Environment variables`

Here you have to create 3 new variables:

```
► PATH
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\gnuplot\bin

► gnuplot
C:\Program Files (x86)\gnuplot\bin

► GNUPLOT_LIB
C:\Program Files (x86)\gnuplot\demo
```

**Step 2: Edit TexStudio**
Go to TexStudio and click on `Options` -> `Configure TexStudio` -> `Commands`

here you need to update the upper both commands

```
► LaTeX
"C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/latex.exe" -src -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

► PdfLaTeX
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -shell-escape -enable-write18 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

**Step 3: Code with Gnuplot in Latex**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{gnuplot}[terminal=pdf]
        set terminal pdf enhanced size 14.5cm, 4cm
        set key top left
        set xlabel 'x [1]'
        set ylabel 'y [1]'

        f1(x)=sin(x**2)

        plot f1(x) title 'y_1 = sin(x^2)'
    \end{gnuplot}
    \caption{Plot}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```